# the most compact way to write swapping keys and values in hash in perl

Tags: perl

I want to create a new hash by swapping keys and values in a hash in perl. Note this is to be done such that the keys for duplicate values are put into an array, which is different from what `reverse` does.

I can obviously do a loop for this. But I am not sure whether it can be done in a compact form such as using `map` etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Define “compact”; then tell us why this is a laudable goal. Short and unreadable loses you points in my grading book.

Comment: @tchrist: I meant to say "more functional-like". I believe avoiding explicit loops can gain some efficiency in languages like matlab, R, python, as well as perl. Maybe not every case, but generally true. Am I right?

Comment: No, not right.  Do it if it makes code that makes more sense to you, not for efficiency.

Answer (score 8):

You can do a "compact" loop like this;

```
my %orig = # whatever
my %rev;
push @{$rev{$orig{$_}}}, $_ for keys %orig;
```

Note that all the values of the "reversed" hash will be arrays with this.

Comment: Thank you. That is basically what I said with the loop approach. What I am trying to ask is: can I declare a new hash once and for all, or not to explicitly declare a new hash, just like `%orig = map { $orig{$_} => $_ } keys(%orig);`?

Comment: I don't know of one. What's your problem with declaring a new hash?

Answer (score 1):

Functional like this?

```
my %orig = ( 1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c', 65 => 'a' );
my $new_hash = List::Util::reduce { push @{ $a->{$orig{$b}} }, $b; $a } {}, keys %orig;
```

For some reason, wrapping a reduce call in a hash-dereference seems to break the &-prototype magic, but you can avoid the new variable by:

```
%orig = %{ List::Util::reduce sub { push @{ $a->{$orig{$b}} }, $b; $a }, {}, keys %orig };
```

If you want to avoid the interior reference to %orig, say if the original hash the result from some other expression, pretend perl has pairlists:

```
%orig = %{ List::Util::reduce sub { push @{ $a->{ $b->[0] } }, $b->[1]; $a }, {},
    @{ List::Util::reduce sub { ! @$a || $#{ $a->[-1] } ? push @$a, [ $b ] : push @{ $a->[-1] }, $b; $a }, [],
        reverse %orig
    }
};
```

Prettier with some utility functions:

```
sub flatten_hashref { %{$_[0]} }
sub flatten_arrayref { @{$_[0]} }
sub pairlist { reduce { ! @$a || $#{ $a->[-1] } ? push @$a, [ $b ] : push @{ $a->[-1] }, $b; $a } [], @_ }

%orig =
    flatten_hashref
    reduce { push @{ $a->{ $b->[0] } }, $b->[1]; $a } {},
    flatten_arrayref
    pairlist
    reverse
    %orig;
```